# sort Linux не сортирует дату по ключу -М

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сортировка, дата

Есть такая проблема при использовании команды sort. Есть файл с таким содержимым:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне надо выполнить сортировку по дате, но она все равно делается по алфавиту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: А колонку кто указывать будет?

Comment: @AlexeyTen при использовании sort family.txt -M -k 1 так же ничего не происходит

Comment: Хм, а кто вас сказал, что -M это сортировка по дате?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Терминал, и любой источник в интернете. Если ввести sort --help, то ключ -М указан как сортировка месяцу

Comment: А если таки прочитать man sort?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 4):

опция `-M` — это сортировка по месяцам: `(unknown) < 'JAN' < ... < 'DEC'`.

для вашего случая надо преобразовать интересующее вас поле так, чтобы данные в нём были записаны в «естественном» порядке: сначала более значимые, затем менее.

т.е., чтобы вместо `число/месяц/год` было `год/месяц/число`.

и потом уже отсортировать по данному полю.

---

например, такое преобразование можно сделать с помощью программы *sed*:

```
$ cat файл
proc  11/09/1999
bin   25/06/2001
boot  06/01/1999
etc   17/08/1987
var   20/02/1999
$ cat файл | sed -r 's,([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}),\3/\2/\1,' | sort -k 2
etc   1987/08/17
boot  1999/01/06
var   1999/02/20
proc  1999/09/11
bin   2001/06/25
```

при необходимости поле можно преобразовать и «назад», к требуемому «неестественному» порядку:

```
$ cat файл | sed -r 's,([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}),\3/\2/\1,' | sort -k 2 | sed -r 's,([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}),\3/\2/\1,'
etc   17/08/1987
boot  06/01/1999
var   20/02/1999
proc  11/09/1999
bin   25/06/2001
```